# What's the solid way to process and send the errors to NewRelic using Slim PHP Framework?

Tags: php, newrelic, slim

I'm using Slim Framework in the project. 
It was quite easy to setup the NewRelic transactions in Slim Framework using its hooks.

But what would be the best way to process any "common" errors? I am not talking about the custom ones. If something goes wrong or there would be any syntax errors in the project, how could I catch that and send to NewRelic?

I thought it might be setup on the PHP layer itself, it's not in the framework layer. But I don't see any errors in the NewRelic now, when there is a syntax errors in the project.

p.s. Now I have default newrelic loglevel - info (both for newrelic and deamon)

Thanks for any comment and explanation.

Comment: Do you mean (fatal) PHP syntax errors? I think you should catch those at build time, not run time. Do you have unit and functional tests?

Comment: @halfer Yes, I do. Of course the fatal PHP errors would be catched in the tests. But if some file become corrupted on the server, i'd like to be aware about that as fast as possible.

Comment: OK. Do mean an XML file or something like that? If you raise an exception when you cannot parse a file, then when you catch that issue, you would normally feed an error to a logger. Does your logging module allow for a callback to also call another program (NR in this case)? Have a look at various loggers here - maybe a Symfony or Zend component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to add the PHP agents `newrelic_notice_error()` call with a custom error handler in the slim framework;

http://docs.slimframework.com/#Error-Handler

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/configuration/php-agent-api#api-notice-error

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I just wondered why the PHP fatal errors is not sent to NewRelic automatically...